# Is there any solution to access pdf files and documents from phone storage and upload to assets folder with Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am new in Flutter. I want to access pdf files and documents from phone storages and upload to assets folder. Is that possible? Which packages should I use? I know there is path_provider  and permission_handler package but I don't know how to use. There is no tutorial. Pls help me out.

Comment: Do you mean asset folder inside your project?

Comment: Yes. I want to show all of the pdf thumbnails on Screen

Comment: hello, ngenge did you find any solution? I'm also working on this save file to the asset folder from phone storage in flutter.

Comment: Yes ,I found another way to solve this problem but not  particular though. I  collected pdf files from Document of phone storage  using external path and shows their thumbnails without uploading to asset folder bro.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) plugin to pick a file from user's external storage and copy it to the app storage scope. This [faq](https://github.com/miguelpruivo/flutter_file_picker/wiki/FAQ) first question will help you.

Comment: file_picker is nice. But All I want to do is that the app will automatically update all the pdf files  and show their thumbnails image on screen when user press Storage permission as 'allow all the time or allow' .  No need to pick by hand.